# How to mute notifications at night?

Tags: 8.1, notifications, nokia-lumia-1020, quiet-hours

I would like to have my phone suspend all notifications between preset hours. Manualy turning sounds off and on is no option. I'm using a Nokia Lumia 1020 with Windows Phone 8.1.

So far I've only found one app called "quiet hours" but it doesn't work on WP 8.1

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work in 8.1? Are you talking about Quiet Hours in Settings?

Comment: Have you tried the [built-in Quiet Hours feature](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/how-to/wp8/cortana/quiet-hours-and-cortana)?

Comment: @Shawn I think he's talking about [this app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/quiet-hours/f347a36b-80c0-430f-8631-e55046ee5a2a).

Comment: Quiet Hours should work/be available when you have Cortana available (as 'Quiet Hours' is part-of Cortana).

Comment: @Indrek Ah, I see. I'd definitely recommend the built-in Quiet Hours.

Comment: @Indrek may I suggest you to convert your first comment in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should try the built-in Quiet hours feature. It can work **only with Cortana** as it is a part of Cortana.

When quiet hours is on, any phone calls you receive will go straight to voicemail, and all notifications will be silent (unless you've told Cortana you'd like to hear from the people in your inner circle).

To turn on quiet hours during night automatically follow these steps :

1. Go to Cortana's notebook
2. Open Quiet hours

[image: Cortana's notebook]

3. Turn on Automatic rules and choose your timing

[image: Automatic setting of quiet hours]

Calls and messages will be shown in action centre where you can check it later.

[image: Quiet hours in action centre]

There is much more functionality in Quiet hours like automatic replies, etc... You can find more information about Quiet hours in these websites.

1. [Quiet hours in Windows phone](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/how-to/wp8/cortana/quiet-hours-and-cortana)
2. [Quiet hours in Windows10](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/set-quiet-hours-in-windows-10)